# Can I open a workbook using Excel.createWorkbook(base64) that has been encrypted?

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I know how to use the base64-encoded bytes of a file to create an excel workbook using office.js. The bytes I'm using represent a password-protected (encrypted) Excel workbook.  When I use

```
Excel.createWorkbook(base64)
```

it prompts the user to enter a password.  However, the user will not know the password.

Is there a way to specify the password in code so the file will be opened without prompting the user to enter a password?

Comment: Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: `Type: product feature request` at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but there is no way to do this in Office.js at this time.